# React native unable to download JS bundle in windows phone

Tags: windows, react-native

Getting this error

> React native unable to download JS bundle

in windows desktop when I uploaded zip file on hockeyapp through visual studio.When I stop react native server still getting same error on same system.

I am not able to run this code on another machine.

Answer (score 1):

Previously I was not able to install my Windows application (created in react native) in another Windows system using the hockey app. I created app packages in visual studio 2017 but was getting an error: "unable to download js bundle", because I was not using offline bundle.

So to create debug or release bundle to run on another devices use this command-

```
**react-native bundle --platform windows --entry-file index.windows.js --bundle-output windows/{your project name}/ReactAssets/index.windows.bundle --assets-dest windows/{your project name}/ReactAssets** 
**--dev false** (mandatory if you want to create release bundle else not )
```

In my case I was using wrong slash in path in the assets path of above command.

After this step create app packages in visual studio. Upload to HockeyApp or somewhere to distribute your app. Now you will not get this error

Comment: Thanks so much! This finally worked for me, I just had to change one thing. Index.windows.js was just index.js for me. so:  react-native bundle --platform windows --entry-file index.js --bundle-output windows/{your project name}/ReactAssets/index.windows.bundle --assets-dest windows/{your project name}/ReactAssets --dev false

Comment: Thanks generating a bundle worked for me. Now, following these steps to generate to release apk. store > create Package > release x86, x64. This generates .ps1 file. Running this file installs my app on windows. However, when I run it search for bundle. Could you share steps to generate .exe with bundle